# DB Error: unknown error (Tablespace is missing for table .civicrm_setting)

Tags: wordpress, database, error

i just restarted my PC which has a locally hosted dev version of CiviCRM in WordPress, and now get the following error on initialization...

```
Initialization Error

Array (
  [callback] => Array
     (
         [0] => CRM_Core_Error
         [1] => simpleHandler
     )

  [code] => -1
  [message] => DB Error: unknown error
  [mode] => 16
  [debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)  [nativecode=1812 **
Tablespace is missing for table `ieditims`.`civicrm_setting`.]
  [type] => DB_Error
  [user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)  [nativecode=1812 **
Tablespace is missing for table `ieditims`.`civicrm_setting`.]
   [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix=""
 info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain,
component_id, created_date, created_id FROM civicrm_setting WHERE
(domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)  [nativecode=1812 ** Tablespace is
missing for table `ieditims`.`civicrm_setting`.]"]
```

Please help!!!

Joe.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant underlying error is hidden in that long message:

> ** Tablespace is missing for table ieditims.civicrm_setting.

I am no expert in database administration but it seems this might be related to a corrupted or missing file of your database system.

If your dev system doesn't have very specific civicrm settings, I would try to delete the table `civicrm_setting` in an admin tool like phpmyadmin and recreate it afterwards.
For CiviCRM 4.7.10 the SQL query to create the table would be

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `civicrm_setting` (
>     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Unique name for setting',
>     `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT 'data associated with this group / name combo',
>     `domain_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Which Domain is this menu item for',
>     `contact_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FK to Contact ID if the setting is localized to a contact',
>     `is_domain` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is this setting a contact specific or site wide setting?',
>     `component_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Component that this menu item belongs to',
>     `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'When was the setting created',
>     `created_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FK to civicrm_contact, who created this setting',
>     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>     UNIQUE KEY `index_domain_contact_name` (`domain_id`,`contact_id`,`name`),
>     KEY `FK_civicrm_setting_domain_id` (`domain_id`),
>     KEY `FK_civicrm_setting_contact_id` (`contact_id`),
>     KEY `FK_civicrm_setting_component_id` (`component_id`),
>     KEY `FK_civicrm_setting_created_id` (`created_id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci